# Can't convert aiohttp request to text while using rule34 api

Tags: python, python-asyncio, freeze, aiohttp

I wanted to make a request to rule34 api using aiohttp, but when I use `text()` or `json()` method the program freezes:

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def foo():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        r = await session.get('https://api.rule34.xxx/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&json=1&limit=1000')
    print('got response') #ok
    text = await r.text() #freezes
    print(text) #never reaches

asyncio.run(foo())
```

But when I use `limit=1` in URL it works normally.

Also it works with requests library with any limit value:

```py
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.rule34.xxx/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&json=1&limit=1000')
print(r.text)
```

I tried to use debugger and noticed that `r._body` was `None` before `await r.text()` was called and the data I need is located at `r.content._buffer` and looks like `deque([b'data'])`, so I tried to use it, but then I noticed that the data isn't complete, like it isn't downloaded completely:

[image: _buffer value].

Maybe because of the `r` wasn't awaited or I don't know, but I can't use `await r` because it throws an exception, or `await r.text()` because it freezes. So I can't even find the reason why it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your interaction with `aiohttp` needs to be inside the `ClientSession` context manager, so you need (note the change in indentation):

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def foo():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        r = await session.get('https://api.rule34.xxx/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&json=1&limit=1000')
        print('got response')
        text = await r.text()
        print(text)

asyncio.run(foo())
```

This successfully prints a JSON response from the API.